# Specifying Seed Number in RAND() function

Tags: python, sql, sample, random-seed

I'm using SQL in Python.

I'm running a sample set of 100 from a population of data (1mn+ rows). I am using the following function:

RAND() <= 0.0025
LIMIT 100

I am unable to get a good sample as the fields are duplicating (there is no duplication in data). If i change the seed number- it gets better.

I tried searching what to put as seed number & how seed number works but couldn't find anything relevant.

I want to know why setting 0.0025 would be better than 0.45 in an instance?

Comment: `0.0025` isn't a seed number, it's a probability (in this case "select approximately 0.25% of rows").

Comment: You haven't shared with us which SQL Server you are using (Microsoft, Postgres, MySQL, etc).  Also, you haven't shown your code, your output, or the issue you are having with it.  As @AKX pointed out, you aren't providing a seed number here at all.